# ListView in AlertDialog, stop it from changing height of dialog

Tags: android

I've got a custom view set for my AlertDialog with an EditText and ListView.  The EditText acts as a filter for the list.  Right now the whole dialog is resizing based on the contents of the list when the user filters it.  How could I set the list to be a fixed height based on screen size so that it doesn't resize?  For example, have the list always take up 40% of the screen height.  I tried weights but it didn't help.  Here is what I currently have.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dialog shrinks its content at a very low level. I tried setting all of the top level views' height to `MATCH_PARENT` after the dialog gets created, but still it didn't change anything. So let's try a different approach. A common one is to listen to when the window does layout with a ViewTreeObserver (a dialog has its own window). So, assuming that your ListView has enough items to initially grow the dialog to the maximum allowed size, we'll change its layout height to a constant. Then, when its adapter contents change, it won't shrink.

In your DialogFragment's `onStart` method is where this trick should happen.

```
        val list = dlog.dialog.findViewById(R.id.results)
        list.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (list.height > 0) {
                    list.layoutParams.height = list.height
                    list.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here to adjust the size of the dialog,

so first you inflate your XML to a view and add it to your dialog.

then you create a `Rect` and make the size of the `Rect` equal to the size of the screen.

Then change the created `View` and resize this with an equation like 60% of the size of the `Rect` which actually is the size of the screen.

here is a code  **you need to modify it according to your code since you didnt provide any code**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_dialog1, null);
            Your-Dialog.setContentView(view); //add the XML to your Dialog

// this if is an demonstration of 'if your device is a tablet` do the following...     
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL
                && density.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH )
        {
            Rect displayRectangle = new Rect(); // Create a Rect
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayRectangle); // add the size of the screen to the Rect
            view.setMinimumWidth((int)(displayRectangle.width() * 0.60f)); // give the dialog a width of 60% of the screen size
            view.setMinimumHeight((int)(displayRectangle.height() * 0.50f)); // give the dialog a height of 50%
        }
```

hope you got the idea, and this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, it works somewhat but it doesn't limit the maximum height so the dialog can still resize if it initially has a lot of list items.  I don't see any setMaximumHeight function, so any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `setMaxHeight` but have you tried to change the value of `0.50f`